# click noise at the start of the audio play by DirectShow

Tags: c++, directshow

I am trying to code DirectShow Audio playback.
I hear the click noise at the start of the play of every media(mp3).
Googled and I see SyncUsingStreamOffset() but no help.
Am I doing wrong? or any workaround suggestion appreciated.

```
IAMGraphStreams* pSyncUsing;
m_pMediaControl->QueryInterface(&pSyncUsing);
pSyncUsing->SyncUsingStreamOffset(TRUE);

HRESULT hr = m_pMediaControl->Run();
if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
  transportState = TransportState::PLAYING;
}
```

Comment: Does the mp3 file do that too? Is it a file or generated? Starting a wave at center or with a fade-in might help. Depends on your actual problem and the question does not have much information...

Comment: Phil, thanks for the comment.
These are collections of MP3s ripped from CDs.
Playing by other players like WMP shows no problem.
Fade-in is what I am considering but definitely my code is missing something.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the cause of the click noise problem.
In the original code, instanciated SampleGrabber for later use of FFT/Visualization.
I thought it just passes through the stream but not, maybe causing some latency problem?

[image: https://gyazo.com/02d5375641c2bdc7fe1805d2eb37d042]

If I remove this filter, the click noise goes away.

Comment: This should be an edit to your question since it is not the answer exactly. Sample Grabber does not add latency but you might be adding just to buffer during processing and it results in a glitch. Apparently your question is incomplete since you just added a really important detail and then it's still unclear what are the media types on pins, and what you are doing in Sample Grabber processing. The glitch is certainly related to your code and framework overall is flawlessly doing its job here.